# Caused by:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$DuplicateTaskException:Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

> Caused by:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$DuplicateTaskException:Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.

I am getting this issue in android studio 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting same issue in android studio 4.1.2

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

    > org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$DuplicateTaskException: Cannot add task 'generateSafeArgsDebug' as a task with that name already exists.
```

because of same plugin id add in module level gradle so please check that

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
  //remove duplicated id added hear and re sync gradle
 // id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
  id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

in your case check what you added **multi plugins id wrapper** so remove that and then sync
after that if you see SUCCESSFUL sync then problem solved